# How does restriction of scalars interact with tensor products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Say that we have a morphism of commutative rings $f: R \to S$. Does the restriction of scalars functor $f^*: S \text{Mod} \to R \text{Mod}$ commute with tensor products? In other words, I would like to know if we have an isomorphism of $R$-modules:
$$f^*(V \otimes_S V') \cong f^*V \otimes_R f^*V'.$$ 
If it does not hold in general, then under what conditions is it true?

The reason I am wondering is that it seems that an $S$-bilinear map $\phi: V \times V' \to V''$ determines an $R$-bilinear map under restriction of scalars.

I get the feeling that it is not quite right to say that $f^*$ is a monoidal functor, but I am not sure what the correct relationship to tensor products should be.

Comment: Take $L|K$ be a non-trivial field extension, $V=V'=S=L$, $R=K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will denote the restriction by $M \mapsto M|_R$. We always have a canonical homomorphism of $R$-modules
$$\theta_{M,N} : M|_R \otimes_R N|_R \to (M \otimes_S N)|_R,\quad m \otimes n \mapsto m \otimes n$$
where $M,N$ are two $S$-modules. This is because the map
$$M|_R \times N|_R \to (M \otimes_S N)|_R,\quad (m,n) \mapsto m \otimes n$$
is $R$-bilinear, so that we can use the [universal property of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules) (that is, its definition). There is also a natural homomorphism of $R$-modules $R \to S|_R$. These maps endow $M \mapsto M|_R$ with the structure of a [lax monoidal functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) $(\mathbf{Mod}_S,\otimes_S) \to (\mathbf{Mod}_R,\otimes_R)$. This amounts to saying that the maps above are natural (in the sense of category theory, i.e. they are components of a natural transformation) and compatible with each other in a certain way.

In general, it is not a [strong monoidal functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor). This happens only when $R \to S$ is an isomorphism of rings (since for a strong monoidal functor, also the unit map needs to be an isomorphism). But your question is only about the homomorphisms $\theta_{M,N}$.

Notice that $\theta_{M,N}$ is the component of a natural transformation of two functors $\mathbf{Mod}_S \times \mathbf{Mod}_S \to \mathbf{Mod}_R$, both of which are *cocontinuous in each variable*. This is because scalar restriction is a [cocontinuous functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocontinuous+functor) and the tensor product is cocontinuous in each variable (in fact, both of these functors are left adjoints). Now, since $S$ generates $\mathbf{Mod}_S$ under colimits, it follows formally that $\theta_{M,N}$ is an isomorphism for all $M,N \in \mathbf{Mod}_S$ if and only if this is the case for $M = N = S$. In this case, the map $\theta_{S,S}$ can be identified with the multiplication homomorphism
$$S \otimes_R S \to S, \quad a \otimes b \mapsto ab,$$
which of course does not have to be an isomorphism (for example, when $R$ is a field, this is the case iff $\dim_R(S) \leq 1$).

Actually, this map is an isomorphism if and only if $R \to S$ is an [epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism) in the category of commutative rings (since, in general, a morphism $X \to Y$ in a category with pushouts is an epimorphism iff the codiagonal $Y \sqcup_X Y \to Y$ is an isomorphism). Notice that epimorphisms of commutative rings don't have to be surjective (for example, every localization is an epimorphism). More on the structure of epimorphisms can be found in

> Séminaire d'Algèbre commutative dirigé par Pierre Samuel 1967/89. Les épimorphismes d'anneaux. Available at [Nundam](http://www.numdam.org/item/SAC_1967-1968__2_/)

---

Appendix. There is a more general observation which allows you to get the lax monoidal structure on $M \mapsto M|_R$ if you already know the strong monoidal structure on $N \mapsto N \otimes_R S$, its left adjoint. Namely, if $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a strong monoidal functor (actually, [oplax](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oplax+monoidal+functor) suffices) and $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}$ is right adjoint to $F$ with unit $\eta$ and counit $\varepsilon$, then $G$ carries the structure of a lax monoidal functor: We take
$$G(X) \otimes G(Y) \xrightarrow{\eta} G(F(G(X) \otimes G(Y))) \to G(F(G(X)) \otimes F(G(Y)) ) \xrightarrow{\varepsilon \otimes \varepsilon} G(X \otimes Y)$$
and
$$1_{\mathcal{C}} \xrightarrow{\eta} G(F(1_{\mathcal{C}})) \to G(1_{\mathcal{D}}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!